# Problems implementing sidebar navigation using Angular2 and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a web application that utilizes bootstrap's sidebar navigation. My URL looks like:

```
 www.my.url.com/projectName/myPage.html
```

The html is:

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" style="overflow: auto;font-family:verdana;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 200;background-color: #002663;top: 0px;width: 18%;height: 700px;color: #002663;">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#generalInfo">General<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Specific<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Config</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Authentication</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ETC...</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Environments<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#env1">Env 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#env2">Env 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#env3">Env 3</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

<div class="container" style="width:80%;float:left">


      <div class="tab-content" style="padding: 22px 0px 29px 88px;">

      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="generalInfo"></div>


      <div class="tab-pane" id="env1"></div>


      <!-- ETC... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The actual implementation of the html doesn't matter, just to show what classes and structure I am using for the content.  When I click on one option with a valid href, instead of loading in the content, it loads as:

```
 www.my.url.com/projectName/#env1
```

When I want it to just show the hidden div class.  This code worked with tabs, but when I tried to modify it to a sidebar instead, it stops working.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `tab-content` and `tab-pane` class, but I can't find any examples on how to change it for sidebar navigation.  Any insight would help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself...To stop the nav bar from linking to other pages, just assign your `<a>` anchors as `data-toggle="tab"`.